# translateZ element still looks flat when rotating parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a "rotate on hover" effect on a div and I want to make it so when it's being rotated the elements inside of it seem to be closer to the viewer and have more depth with regards to the background. However, applying `translateZ();` makes them look bigger, but they still look "stuck" to the background.

So far, I tried to apply both `perspective` and `transform: perspective();` properties to the parent element and `transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the child element, but it still looks glued to the background.

So to be clear, [this is what I want to recreate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BLSO.gif)

But [this is what I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exlrF.gif)

```js
let gridElements = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-member');

    let magify = (container, inner, adjust) => {
      // Mouse
      var mouse = {
        _x: 0,
        _y: 0,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        updatePosition: function (event) {
          var e = event || window.event;
          this.x = e.clientX - this._x;
          this.y = (e.clientY - this._y) * -1;
        },
        setOrigin: function (e) {
          this._x = e.offsetLeft + Math.floor(e.offsetWidth / 2);
          this._y = e.offsetTop + Math.floor(e.offsetHeight / 2);
        },
        show: function () {
          return '(' + this.x + ', ' + this.y + ')';
        },
      };

      // Track the mouse position relative to the center of the container.
      mouse.setOrigin(container);

      //----------------------------------------------------

      var counter = 0;
      var refreshRate = 3;
      var isTimeToUpdate = function () {
        return counter++ % refreshRate === 0;
      };

      //----------------------------------------------------

      var onMouseEnterHandler = function (event) {
        container.style.zIndex = '3';
        update(event);
      };

      var onMouseLeaveHandler = function () {
        container.style.transform = '';
        // inner.children[1].style.transform = '';
        container.style.zIndex = '';
      };

      var onMouseMoveHandler = function (event) {
        if (isTimeToUpdate()) {
          update(event);
        }
      };

      //----------------------------------------------------

      var update = function (e) {
        // Set up multipliers
        var yMult = 0.03;
        var xMult = 0.063;

        var d = document,
          bd = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
          win = window;

        var bdst = $(window).scrollTop();
        var bdsl = bd.scrollLeft;
        var pageX = e.pageX;
        var pageY = e.pageY;
        var offsets = inner.getBoundingClientRect();
        var w = inner.clientWidth || inner.offsetWidth || inner.scrollWidth;
        var h = inner.clientHeight || inner.offsetHeight || inner.scrollHeight;
        var wMultiple = 320 / w;
        var offsetX = 0.52 - (pageX - offsets.left - bdsl) / w;
        var offsetY = 0.52 - (pageY - offsets.top - bdst) / h;
        var dy = pageY - offsets.top - bdst - h / 2;
        var dx = pageX - offsets.left - bdsl - w / 2;
        var yRotate = (offsetX - dx) * (yMult * wMultiple);
        var xRotate = (dy - offsetY) * (xMult * wMultiple);

        var imgCSS;

        imgCSS =
          'perspective(' +
          w * 3 +
          'px) rotateX(' +
          xRotate * 1 +
          'deg) rotateY(' +
          yRotate * 1 +
          'deg)';

        // var innerCSS = 'rotateX(' + xRotate * 0.2 + 'deg) rotateY(' + yRotate * 0.35 + 'deg) translateZ(30px)';

        // inner.children[1].style.transform = innerCSS;
        container.style.transform = imgCSS;
      };

      var updateTransformStyle = function (x, y) {
        var style = 'rotateX(' + x + 'deg) rotateY(' + y + 'deg)';
        container.style.transform = style;
        container.style.webkitTransform = style;
        container.style.mozTranform = style;
        container.style.msTransform = style;
        container.style.oTransform = style;
      };

      //--------------------------------------------------------

      container.onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
      container.onmouseleave = onMouseLeaveHandler;
      container.onmouseenter = onMouseEnterHandler;
    };

    magify(gridElements[0], gridElements[0].children[0], 0.5);
```

```css
body {
      background: black;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    #container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 1500px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    #container > div {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background: red;
      perspective: 30px;
      perspective-origin: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      align-content: center;
      background: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/1018/3914/2935.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #container > div > div {
      transform: translateZ(20px);
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    #container > div p {
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="grid-member large">
    <div><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's two completely different mechanisms though: what you want to implement is text moving around, being offset from its center position. What your code does though is transform the text in the exact same plane as the image. Just move the text up the tree once so it's a direct child of the container div, then change its style separately (either using transform2D or by simply using `position: relative` and left/top values)

Comment: Well isn't `translateZ()` supposed to bring the text to a forward plane altogether and render its transforms on another plane?

Comment: Yes, but since the text is a child of the image div, all translations to the image div are also applied to all its children. In the example of what you want to achieve, the text isn't transformed perspectivically, it just moves laterally. Also: just to be clear: you can move the text really "close to the camera" if you will, and it will get big and blurry. But it will *still* look like glued to the image because it's the exact same transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it with `translate()`

```js
let gridElements = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-member');
var textContainer = document.querySelector("#text");
    let magify = (container, inner, adjust) => {
      // Mouse
      var mouse = {
        _x: 0,
        _y: 0,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        updatePosition: function (event) {
          var e = event || window.event;
          this.x = e.clientX - this._x;
          this.y = (e.clientY - this._y) * -1;
        },
        setOrigin: function (e) {
          this._x = e.offsetLeft + Math.floor(e.offsetWidth / 2);
          this._y = e.offsetTop + Math.floor(e.offsetHeight / 2);
        },
        show: function () {
          return '(' + this.x + ', ' + this.y + ')';
        },
      };

      // Track the mouse position relative to the center of the container.
      mouse.setOrigin(container);

      //----------------------------------------------------

      var counter = 0;
      var refreshRate = 3;
      var isTimeToUpdate = function () {
        return counter++ % refreshRate === 0;
      };

      //----------------------------------------------------

      var onMouseEnterHandler = function (event) {
        container.style.zIndex = '3';
        update(event);
      };

      var onMouseLeaveHandler = function () {
        container.style.transform = '';
        // inner.children[1].style.transform = '';
             textContainer.style.transform = "";
        container.style.zIndex = '';
      };

      var onMouseMoveHandler = function (event) {
        if (isTimeToUpdate()) {
          update(event);
        }
      };

      //----------------------------------------------------

      var update = function (e) {
        // Set up multipliers
        var yMult = 0.03;
        var xMult = 0.063;

        var d = document,
          bd = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
          win = window;

        var bdst = $(window).scrollTop();
        var bdsl = bd.scrollLeft;
        var pageX = e.pageX;
        var pageY = e.pageY;
        var offsets = inner.getBoundingClientRect();
        var w = inner.clientWidth || inner.offsetWidth || inner.scrollWidth;
        var h = inner.clientHeight || inner.offsetHeight || inner.scrollHeight;
        var wMultiple = 320 / w;
        var offsetX = 0.52 - (pageX - offsets.left - bdsl) / w;
        var offsetY = 0.52 - (pageY - offsets.top - bdst) / h;
        var dy = pageY - offsets.top - bdst - h / 2;
        var dx = pageX - offsets.left - bdsl - w / 2;
        var yRotate = (offsetX - dx) * (yMult * wMultiple);
        var xRotate = (dy - offsetY) * (xMult * wMultiple);

        var imgCSS;
        let dirX = yRotate;
        let dirY = xRotate - ( 2 * xRotate);
        
        
        var textStyle = `translate(${dirX}px, ${dirY}px)`;
        textContainer.style.transform = textStyle;
        imgCSS =
          'perspective(' +
          w * 3 +
          'px) rotateX(' +
          xRotate * 1 +
          'deg) rotateY(' +
          yRotate * 1 +
          'deg)';

        // var innerCSS = 'rotateX(' + xRotate * 0.2 + 'deg) rotateY(' + yRotate * 0.35 + 'deg) translateZ(30px)';

        // inner.children[1].style.transform = innerCSS;
        container.style.transform = imgCSS;
      };

      var updateTransformStyle = function (x, y) {
        var style = 'rotateX(' + x + 'deg) rotateY(' + y + 'deg)';
        container.style.transform = style;
        container.style.webkitTransform = style;
        container.style.mozTranform = style;
        container.style.msTransform = style;
        container.style.oTransform = style;
      };

      //--------------------------------------------------------

      container.onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
      container.onmouseleave = onMouseLeaveHandler;
      container.onmouseenter = onMouseEnterHandler;
    };

    magify(gridElements[0], gridElements[0].children[0], 0.5);
```

```css
body {
      background: black;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    #container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 1500px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    #container > div {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      background: red;
      perspective: 30px;
      perspective-origin: center;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      align-content: center;
      background: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/1018/3914/2935.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #container > div > div {
       font-size: 26px;
    }
    #container > div p {
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 800;
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="grid-member large">
    <div id="text"><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```